# AMD Open64: Optimized math functions

Tags: instruction-set, vectormath, amd-processor

Does Open64 has something equivalent to [Intel Short Vector Math Library Operations](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/lin/intref_cls/common/intref_bk_svml_ops.htm).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I more or less figured it out. AMD OpenMP ships with AMD's math library ACML. ACML has functions similar to those in Intel's library.

Answer (score 0):

Open64 is just a compiler, so you can link what ever library you needs to the object file that open64 compiler generates.